# Question concerning the proof of Baire's Theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Baire's Theorem: Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and let $D_n, n \in \mathbb N$ be open, dense subsets of X. Then also $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} D_n$ is dense in X.

In the following, $U_r(x)$ will denote the open ball of $x$ and $K_r(x)$ the closed ball of $x$ (with radius $r$ respectively).

Proof: We need to show that, for all $x \in X$ and $r > 0$, $U_r(x) \cap \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} D_n \neq \varnothing$. Let $x \in X$ and $r > 0$ be arbitrary, but fixed. By induction, we then define a
sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} ⊂ X $ and $(r_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} ⊂ \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ by

i) $K_{r_{n+1}}(x_{n+1}) ⊂ D_n \cap U_{r_{n}}(x_n)$

ii) $r_n \le {1 \over n}$

I want to skip the construction of such a sequence for a given $x$ and $r$.

Having constructed $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $(r_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ satisfying i) and ii), we obtain $x_n \in K_{r_{n}}(x_{n}) ⊂ D_{n-1} \cap U_{r_{n-1}}(x_{n-1}) ⊂ U_{r_{n-1}}(x_{n-1}) ⊂...⊂ U_{r_{m}}(x_{m})$ for all $n \gt m$. Thus $d(x_n, x_m) < r_m < {1 \over m}$ for all $n \gt m$. This implies that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy-sequence in X.

I also want to skipt the last part, where we show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \in U_r(x) \cap \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} D_n$.

My question: Where did I use that $K_{r_{n+1}}(x_{n+1})$ is a closed ball? Is this needed for $x_n$ to be a Cauchy-sequence? Why?

Comment: Second question: Cauchyness of $(x_n)$ ensures the limit $x$ exist since that is a complete metric space. First question: $(x_k)_{k\geq n}$ is a subset of $K_{r_n}(x_n)$ so that the limit point $x$ belongs to $K_{r_n}(x_n)$ since the closed ball is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n$ we have $\{x_m:m>n\} \subset  U_{r_{n+1}}(x_{n+1}).$ So for every $n$ we have $$y=\lim_{m\to \infty}x_m\in Cl(  U_{r_{n+1}}  (x_{n+1})) =K_{r_{n+1}}(x_{n+1})\subset D_n\cap U_{r_n}(x_n)\subset D_n\cap U_r(x).$$

If we tried to work only with $U_{n_{r+1}}(x_{n+1})\subset U_{r_n}(x_n)$ we might find ourselves in trouble.

For example, if $X=\mathbb R$ and $x=0 \not \in D_1$, we might have $U_{r_n}(x_n)=(0,2^{-n}a).$ Then $(x_n)_n$ converges to $0$, which is  not  a member of $\cap_nD_n.$

So we need  $Cl(U_{r_{n+1}}(x_{n+1}))\subset U_{r_n}(x_n) .$

Footnote: The usual notation for $U_r(x)$ is $B(x,r).$ And $K_r(x)=\overline {B(x,r)}=Cl(B(x,r)).$